# NSUIElement dock icon still appears

Tags: cocoa

I added the NSUIElement with value 1 in my info.plist but the dock icon still appears.
Here is my code

```
<key>NSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is actually called `LSUIElement` (see [Launch Services Info.plist keys documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256)).

Comment: I changed the key to "LSUIElement" but my application is not running as an agent. I tested in another application and it worked.

Comment: Try a clean rebuild. Also, check the built product's `Info.plist` to verify that the key is in fact called `LSUIElement` there.

Comment: Actually, both `NSUIElement` and `LSUIElement` will work. Most probably you just need to clean your target.